# Bash while read to include if

Tags: bash

I have the below which is part of a Nagios query running every 5 minutes that is looking at a MySQL table. It loops looking for all the IP's and returns them along with a count of how many times each one appears and if any go over 30 all results are emailed to me. Either way the table is cleared after each check. This works fine.

What I now want adding is if the count is > 100 that it executes a url. But I need the ip to translate to the server name.

This url is a get and does some server side processing elsewhere. The URL will be like:

https://api.xxxxx.com/?id=AA123&to=123456789&content=server1%20myapp%20restart

I'm not sure how to construct this, I've attempted below in the new code section do I need to do another while read, or can I add this to the existing? I have put "STUCK" where I'm not sure how to reference the variable to then return server1 etc. Also I guess the curl command would be now included in my email.

Current code:

```
while read ip count; do

            message=$message" -- $ip : $count -- "

done <<< "$result"
```

New code:

```
192.168.50.10=server1
192.168.50.11=server2
192.168.50.12=server3
192.168.50.13=server4



while read ip count; do
message=$message" -- $ip : $count -- "
if [[ $count -gt 100 ]]; then
curl "https://api.xxxxx.com/?id=AA123&to=123456789&content="STUCK"%20myapp%20restart"
fi
done <<< "$result"
```

I have edited as suggested but I'm getting Syntax error: redirection unexpected.

```
while read ip count; do 
    #variables
    str1="https://api.xxxxx.com/?id=AA123&to=123456789&content="
    str2="%20myapp%20start"
    str3="$str1 $name $str2"
    name=$(lookup () {
    awk -v q="$1" '$1 == q { print $2; exit 0 }
        END { exit 1 }' <<'________HERE'
    192.168.50.10 server1
    192.168.50.11 server2
    192.168.50.12 server3
    192.168.50.13 server4
   ________HERE
```

})

```
message=$message" -- $ip : $count -- "

if [[ $count -gt 100 ]]; then
echo $str3
fi
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an associative array.  They are available in Bash 4.  For a limited mapping such as yours, if you need it to work on an earlier version of Bash, it would not be too hard to code up a simple replacement; maybe use Awk.

Comment: `if [[$count > "100"]]; then` is a syntax error - it should be `if [[ $count -gt 100 ]]; then` (note the spaces and the use of `-gt` for numerical comparison)

Comment: If your only problem is to translate ips to names then I would recommend you reduce your question to that.

Comment: Maybe not such a stellar duplicate.  A better place to look is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays

Comment: my bash is version 3.2

Comment: I posted an answer to the linked duplicate which should hopefully work for you.  They map from IP to host but doing the reverse mapping is obviously a simple matter of switching the columns in the data.

Comment: yes thanks, was it your answer you were referring to? I have tried to add that but get the issue as shown in edited post.